# Obtaining resolution of the monitor of client through a web app

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask, multiple-monitors

I am trying to develop a web application in python/flask where a part of the web page tells the user the resolution of the monitor they are using, similar to [this](http://www.wallpaperfusion.com/Image/more-grass/22189/). It should still give the same resolution even if the web page is zoomed in or out, [*unlike* this website](http://www.whatismyscreenresolution.com/) and *like* the above. How can I do it through ***either* flask, jquery or javascript**? And if a user uses **multiple monitors**, how can I obtain resolution of ***all/any*** the possible monitors that the user is using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript with the `window.screen` properties : [link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_screen.asp)

```
window.screen.availHeight
window.screen.availWidth
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer, but it shows the resolution of the browser window of the web page... which will change if I zoom in or out...